# resource not found when populating list in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am trying to get a simple list in my android application and fill it with some strings. For this I have implemented the following main activity:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends BaseActivity{

private ArrayList<String> teamList = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> teamListAdapter;
private ListView teamListView;

protected void loadGUI() {
    setContentView(R.layout.main_login);
    teamListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.teamList);
    teamListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.id.teamList, teamList);
    teamListView.setAdapter(teamListAdapter);
    addItem("test");
}

public void addItem(String item) {
    teamList.add(item);
    teamListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

with BaseActivity the class implementing the onCreate methods etc:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

protected Activity mActivity;
protected Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = this;
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadGUI();
}

protected abstract void loadGUI();
}
```

When I try to run this, I get the error:

```
05-09 16:50:04.386: E/AndroidRuntime(12037): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070002 type #0x12 is not valid
```

This error is caused by the function call off addItem, but I do not know what could be the problem with this function. Does anybody see what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in the wrong type of resource to the constructor of the ArrayAdaper.  Parameter 2 should be the the resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong id in the adapter. Try changing this:

```
teamListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.id.teamList, teamList);
```

to this:

```
teamListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teamList);
```